# Слетает фильтр при клике на другую страницу пагинации

Tags: php

После выбора фильтра, формируется новая пагинация (с правильным числом страниц), однако по клику на любую следующую страницу отфильтрованных элементов фильтр слетает и выводятся все элементы из БД, а не те, которые выбрал фильтром. Нужно как-то обновить ссылки пагинации? Или что можно сделать?

Вот класс пагинации.

[Посмотреть и подсказать)))](https://pastebin.com/zYD36Pq8)

Фильтр работает обычным способом - при клике на фильтр Ajax передает в php выбранный фильтр и его значение, php формирует sql запрос и возвращает ответом выбранные элементы из БД. Сразу после выбора фильтра все работает как надо (выводятся только отфильтрованные элементы из БД), но стоит нажать на любую другую страницу в пагинации и фильтр сбивается, и выводятся все элементы из БД, а не только те, которые отфильтровал.

Comment: в этом "классе" настолько всё плохо, что пропадание фильтра - это мелочи. Зачем например, вы по два раза запрашиваете одно и то же из базы данных? И если уж на то пошло, **зачем вам вообще класс пагинации**, если вы каждый раз всё равно выбираете из БД **все** записи?

Comment: а по вопросу - ну так вы сами себе на него и ответили.

Comment: 2 запроса к базе - 1-ый: подсчет кол-ва всех элементов в таблице, 2-ой: формирование лимита для пагинации, по второму Вашему комментарию не понял. Вот все пишут только "ой ужасно как всё" и никто не подскажет как сделать так чтобы было все прекрасно

Comment: "если вы каждый раз всё равно выбираете из БД все записи" - почему ВСЕ записи? в функцию передается запрос аргументом - $sql Например - **$items = $paggi->getItems("SELECT * FROM `table` ".$where." ORDER BY id DESC");** где $where сформированный запрос с фильтрами

Comment: Да какая разница - с аргументом или без? Речь идет о том, что первым запросом вы выбираете **все записи без лимита**. То есть непонятно - зачем вам тогда вообще второй запрос, если вы и так уже все записи получили

Comment: И, кстати, отдельный вопрос. Если уж говорить про "аргументы": зачем там prepare() и execute()? Какой в них смысл?

Comment: Вы можете посоветовать как сделать все одним запросом? Чтобы сначала считалось общее кол-во записей, а потом сформировать лимит? Первый запрос - подсчет кол-ва **красный яблок** - Select * from table Where color = red

Comment: Нет, одним запросом это сделать невозможно, надо два. Но вот первый должен не выбирать все записи, как сейчас, а только подсчитывать количество. То есть **запрашивать у БД количество, а не сами записи**

Comment: по поводу вашего вопроса - в РНР есть функция array_merge() она поможет взять существующий массив и передать в него новое значение существующего элемента. А если элемента нет - то добавить его. Это как раз то что вам нужно. Я надеюсь что где взять массив с GET параметрами, вы уже знаете. результат этой функции надо скормить еще одной, http_build_query()

Comment: Спасибо. Постараюсь исправить запросы и сделать merge. Если у Вас есть еще какие-либо советы, дайте их пожалуйста.

Comment: ну самая главная проблема - это бессмысленность использования prepare и execute. Их надо начать использовать по назначению.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

Все что нужно было сделать это добавить на страницу, на которой выводятся данные php код, который берет гет параметры и на их основе строит запрос к БД. Например если есть

`?price=100 или ?price=100&color=red`, то строить запрос

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE price = '100' AND color = 'red';`

Answer (score 1):

Общее решение - вам надо добавлять параметры фильтрации в url при ajax-запросе, и обновлять пагинацию, с помощью того-же jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'ajax/some.php',
success: function(data){
  history.pushState('data', '', 'https://site.ru/?q='+query);
    ...
  $(".pagination-item").attr('href', window.location.href + "&page"+index);
   ...
}});
```